# Check if all of the elements in one numpy array exist in a second numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone have a more numpy-like way of accomplishing this:

```
def uneven_compare(array1, array2):
    return numpy.all([numpy.any(array2 == elem) for elem in array1])
```

I just want to check if all of the elements in one array exist in a second array.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) :

```
In [6]: array1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 0])

In [7]: array2 = np.array([0, 10, 20, 1, 2, 30, 5])

In [8]: np.in1d(array1, array2)
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [9]: np.all(np.in1d(array1, array2))
Out[9]: True
```